# How to find package, version, documentation for a Haskell name

Tags: haskell, ghci

My concrete problem is this: I ran across the name `throwT` in `Module.hs` in a big Haskell project. I want to know what `throwT` does. I eventually managed to figure this one out as follows:

1. fire up ghci for the project
2. `:load Module.hs` followed by `:i throwT`

   `throwT :: Monad m => e -> Control.Monad.Trans.Either.EitherT e m r 
      -- Defined in ‘Data.EitherR’`
3. query [hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=data.eitherr) for `Data.EitherR`, which points at the package `errors`
4. `ghc-pkg list errors` gives `errors-1.4.7`
5. browse hackage to the documentation of that version of the errors package: [throwT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-1.4.7/docs/Data-EitherR.html#v:throwT)

Is there a better way to do this, both in the sense of being more precise (step 3 is not), and less tedious?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `ghc-pkg find-module` instead of `list`, which gives you the installed version of the package containing the module right away:

1. Fire up GHCi
2. `:load YourModule.hs`, get `:info` on your value
3. Use the given module name with `ghc-pkg find-module`.
4. You now know the exact module, package and version.

This still forces you to check the hackage documentation. However, if you add `documentation: true` to your cabal configuration or `--enable-documentation`, cabal will automatically build the documentation during the installation of the given package. Then you can shorten the procedure to

1. Fire up GHCi
2. `:load YourModule.hs`, get `:info` on your value
3. Check your local documentation for the references module.

The local documentation will be stored in your cabal directory, or, if you are in a sandbox, in `.cabal-sandbox/share/doc/<plattform>/index.html`.

Comment: You can also build a local hoogle database and use hoogle locally, but I don't have time to build and check this at the moment. Then should be as easy as `hoogle-local throwT`.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, every module explicitly imports every function it uses. Assuming that `throwT` was used in `Module.hs`, but not defined in it, the first thing to check for is if there is an import statement at the top of `Module.hs` that explicitly imports the function, which would look something like `import Some-Module (throwT, someOtherFunction, possiblyAnotherFunction)`, where `Some-Module` is the module being imported, and the functions within the parenthesis are the only things being imported from that module (this is what an explicit import is). You'd then find `Some-Module` and look for the definition of `throwT`.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Instead, it provides steps how authors can help their users to avoid getting into the situation.

Comment: I wrote this from the understanding that the OP may or `may not` have checked for explicit imports first. That said, their use of `ghc-pkg list errors` probably precludes them from having not done this already, which I did not think about.